# Erlang change value of element in list

Tags: list, replace, erlang, tuples

Hello is there a way to change the value of the head of a list in Erlang

```
 Hd -> store2(Key, N,[New|List],New,false)
```

this is as close I came to changing it **New** is the new element to the Head element of the list

```
store(Key, N, TupleList, New) when is_integer(N), N > 0, is_tuple(New) ->
store2(Key, N, TupleList, New, false).

store2(_Key,_N,[], New, false) -> [New];
  store2(Key, N,List, New, false) -> case fetch(Key, N, List) of
     [] -> List;
     false -> List++[New];
     Hd -> store2(Key, N,[New|List],New,false)
   end.
```

to clarify even further im using a function called fetch that I defined to find an element to replace with another element which is `New`

Comment: `[A | B]` prepends `A` to the list `B` so this should work. Does it not work for you? What result are you getting and what do you expect?

Comment: I get no result actually but when I use `[New]++lists:delete(Hd,List)` I get the wrong result.

Comment: What do you mean by "no result"? `[New | List]` will at least return a list.

Comment: by no result I mean it goes into an infinite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prepend your new head to the tail of `List`.

```
[New|tl(List)]
```

You usually write it as pattern matching

```
some_function(..., [_Old|Tail] = _List, ...)->
    ...
    NewList = [New|Tail],
    ...
```